# Fit image into div | Bootstrap

Tags: css, sass, bootstrap-5, card, horizontal-card

I am trying to fit some images to a horizontal cards made with Bootstrap-5 but i can't fill up the div entirely. I use a main.scss to manage bootstrap css and I have used a some of the classes of bootstrap like '***img-fluid***' and '***img-responsive***' (doesn't work)

I am testing in a card template extracted from boostrap.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/card/#horizontal

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
            <img src="../modulos/post.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="card mb-3 border-light publication-card" style="max-width: 540px;">
            <div class="row g-0">
              <div class="col-md-5">
                <img src="./img/post3.jpg" class="img-fluid rounded-start" alt="...">
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-7">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                  <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="card text-bg-dark">
            <img src="../modulos/post3.jpg" class="card-img" alt="...">
            <div class="card-img-overlay">
              <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
              <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
              <p class="card-text">Last updated 3 mins ago</p>
            </div>
          </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the Sass:

```
 // $primary: #284577;
$primary: #3772FF;

$enable-shadows: true;


//$font-family-base: "Open Sans", sans-serif;


@import "./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";


body {
    color: #35393C;
    background-color: #ECECFF;
}

.container{
    border: 2px solid red; 
}

 // THE CLASS I HAVE TRIED TO FILL UP THE DIV ------------------
.img-fluid{
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}




div[class^='nav']{
    border: 2px solid red;
}

div[class^='a']{
    border: 2px solid red;
}

div[class^='coll']{
    border: 2px solid red;
}

div[class^='drop']{
    border: 2px solid red;
}

div[class^='w-25']{
    border: 2px solid red;
}

div[class^='container']{
    border: 2px solid red;
}

div[class^='row']{
    border: 2px solid red;
}

div[class^='col']{
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

I was trying to adapt the .img-fluid class but doesn't work.
In the vertical card the pic fits perfectly and also I have tried different image format like 4:3 or square but I can't depend on the resolution If I wanna use responsive website.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to give your img a class and set a custom height / width and set object-fit:cover.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Add height 100% in the image:

```
.img-fluid {
    height: 100%;
 }
```

Comment: This answer was reviewed in the [Low Quality Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality). Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code only answers are **not considered good answers**, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are **less useful** to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does and how it solves to question in the OP. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32398480)